# aws s3 public bucket custom domain URL gives not secure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement where I have made my aws s3 bucket as public to access the images inside the bucket.I have created a custom domain in Route 53 with CNAME to the s3 aws public bucket.
I am able to access the image from aws s3 public bucket with custom DNS like `https://mywebsite.abc.xyz/abc/img1.png` but this is giving me `not secure` link as the certificate is missing. I am not sure how to fix this?

One way is to have cloudfront in between but what to define in the root object as this is just s3 bucket to have images stored.

Comment: You can't add ssl certificates directly to an s3 bucket. It has to be done though cloudfront.

Comment: how to achieve this feature through cloudfront? where the distribution will point to s3 bucket with only images, it doesnt have any html pages.

Comment: It does not have to be html page. Any file can be served using cloudfront from s3. One way of setting this up is shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/). But there are many more tutorials out there if you want to go this route.

Comment: The "easiest" method is to use `http` rather than `https`. No certificates required, and still supports a friendly URL. But, it won't support https.

Comment: I am not sure, what did I miss last time, but tried same thing with cloudfront and now it worked

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and AWS pure solution would be to attach an AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) to your cloudfront distribution, which fronts your S3 bucket. You can then enforce HTTPS only protocol on your S3 webapp.

You can follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@lockdown2k17/aws-s3-static-website-hosting-using-ssl-acm-112e6d6b6d97) which walks you through how to achieve this.